# Pass props to a component, React Router V4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I have an app with this components tree:

```
App
   Header
   Main
     Searcher
     List_of_albums
       Album
```

So, the idea is that in the main page I have a searcher of albums and this displays a list of albums after the search. To do this, I am reading a .json file in the component Main and then the props are passed to List_of_albums and Album.

Everything works fine up to this point.

Now I want to acces with a buttom to the info of each Album in a new route: /id_of_the_album.

This buttom is localized in the component Album like this:

```
let albumLink = `/${this.props.id}`
<Link to={albumLink}></Link>
```

To do that, I tried this in the component App:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
  super()
  }

  render () {
   return (
     <Router>
      <Fragment>
       <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' render={() => {
           return(
             <Main />
            )
          }} />

         <Route path='/:id_of_the_album' render={() => {
           return(
             <Profile />
           )
          }} />
          </Switch>
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Where Profile is the new component to show the album details. 
In this new Component I would like to open the jsons of the individual albums with something like this:

```
import singlejson from '../data/""""herethe_id_of_the_album"""".json'
```

but How can I pass to the component profile the id_of_the_album??

Comment: You will not be able to open your json files like this. By the time your app runs in the browser the imports will already be gone. Imports are at compile-time, not at runtime. You will need to fetch these files from your server.

Comment: I have done it doing this and its works:
      var data = require('../data/'+this.props.match.params.id+'.json');

is it wrong?

Comment: First of all the path you are trying to require is a relative file path. But the browser does not have access to the file system for security reasons. Second this path is relative to your app root on YOUR computer. Which folder should this refer to on the client side. Where should this file come from? I can't imagine that this works as you expect it to do. Usually you have to fetch this kind of data from an api. What if you add an album? Do you want to deploy your app every time you add an album to include that file in your bundle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
<Route path='/:id_of_the_album' render={props => <Profile {...props} /> } />
```

Now inside `Profile` component, it should be available by:

`this.props.match.params.id_of_the_album`

Comment: But How Can I pass {...props} to profile since I dont Have this variable "id_of_the_album" defined in the component App?

Comment: `props` will get passed by route component, notice here: `render={props => ......}`, route will pass that id to Profile component :) try this answer it will work, let me know if you have any other doubts.

Comment: @MayankShukla `this.props.match.params.id` is missing `id` when i tried this. how do i get the id? i have `<Route path="/commsmatrix/aggr/:id" render={props => <CommsMatrixAggregateView isReady={this.state.isReady} passMetaBack={this.passMetaBack} {...this.props} />} />`, i can see `match.params` but no `id`

Comment: @shorif2000 id is a parameter, make sure to pass it in the url, in your case url should be: `/commsmatrix/aggr/10` (in place of 10 some value is required), let me know if that doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: @MayankShukla this is what i have done, but it is not working, i am passing `/10`. here is in json `{"path":"/","url":"/","params":{},"isExact":false}` in my `CommsMatrixAggregateView ` component. i am using `v4.2.0`

Comment: @MayankShukla please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633097/how-to-pass-multiple-props-when-using-match

Answer (score 1):

In react router, when you are routing from one component to another component, you will have an object `match` which has many properties within it. One among them is `params` which helps us to identify if any parameter is passed to the child component via the route.

In your case, you can just use `match.params.id_of_the_album` in your child component

[This link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) gives more info on react router.